# Group Actions: Orbit Space 2

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-actions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are $G$-free action ($G$ is a group). Then $X\times Y$ is a $G$-free action via the diagonal action. My question is why $$(X/G) \times Y = (X\times Y)/G ?$$
where $X/G$ and $(X\times Y)/G$ are orbit spaces

Comment: Do you mean $(x,y)\cdot g=(x\cdot g,y\cdot g)$ by diagonal action?